# Как в yandex map api при клике в балуне получить значение атрибута элемента по которому кликнули?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Вот есть такой кусок кода:

```
   myMap.balloon.events.add('click', function (e) {
       ////
    });
```

По нему я определяю клик внутри балуна, у меня внутри него есть кнопка, мне при клике внутри балуна нужно в скрипте определить что был клик именно по кнопке, вообщем использовать .hasClass или по .attr

Или лучше в теге самой кнопки прописать onclick="" ?

Comment: Посмотрите [этот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout?from=SO), там как раз балун с кнопкой

Comment: @Reni напишите ответ, он полезнее комментария со ссылкой. Ресурс по ссылке может оказаться недоступным со временем.